# Jmeter script is not redirecting from application URL to login URL of the tomcat

Tags: jmeter

We have application hosted on Tomcat server cpu261.dev.local with port 8080. following is the URL of the application:

```
URL-1
http://cpu261.dev.local:8080/omnienterprise?tid=1
```

when we hit above URL it is immediately redirects to following URL:

```
URL-2
http://cpu261.dev.local:8080/omnienterprise/ngcore/preLoginAction.action?tid=1&vToken=-1&mid=0&adsLoginId=
```

and then we get the option to enter username. after entering username our Tomcat redirects to following URL:

```
URL-3
http://cpu261.dev.local:8080/omnienterprise/ngcore/loginUserAction.action
```

here we enter Branch code and password to view the dashboard.

This is my actual application flow. I want to make script in JMeter to stress test the applicaiton.

I have created one script,
please find attached screenshot of the JMeter script:

[image: Script for URL 1]

[image: Script for URL 2]

[image: Script for URL 3]

My issue is when i am running the script with URL-1 it somehow doesn't redirecting to URL-2 or not even giving error in the listener
I am using, in the listener response code is 200 OK.

Please find below screenshot of the listener:

[image: Response of the URL 1]

Why is it not redirecting from URL-1 to URL-2? How do I write script for such a scenario?

Comment: Any feedback on answer ? If ok you should accept it and upvote so that others can trust it ?

Answer (score 0):

You're most probably missing a Header, parameter or cookie.

The best way to create a script is to use JMeter recording feature:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html

Comment: Hi, I tried with Header, cookie or parameter. it didn't work. as you can see in the question, we have Tomcat server on which our application is deployed. As we hit URL-1 it directly redirects to URL-2 and then we enter Username and after pressing enter it redirects to URL-3 on that page we enter Branch and password. So in my script of Jmeter, it is not redirecting from URL-1 to URL-2. I have tried giving parameters in all possible ways that I knew. Please help.